# Switch GridView to Listview or vice versa using Recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am using recyclerview to retrieve data from firebase database which is working nicely but i have set default layout manager as linear but i want user must be able to switch from listview to gridview which is not working. It is not changing state when i click on on gridview item.It does nothing remains in the default state as linearlayout manager.

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference category;
    TextView txtfullname;
    RecyclerView recycler_menu;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,MenuViewHolder> adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Menu");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //init firebase
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        category=database.getReference("Category");



        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    //set name for user
    View headerView= navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    txtfullname= headerView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
//    txtfullname.setText(Common.currentUser.getName());

    //Load menu using firebase ui to bind data from frebase to recyclerview

        recycler_menu =findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recycler_menu.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutman();
        recycler_menu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        loadMenu();

    }

    private void layoutman() {
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    }

    private void loadMenu() {
         adapter =new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category, MenuViewHolder>(Category.class,R.layout.menu_item,MenuViewHolder.class,category) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MenuViewHolder viewHolder, Category model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtMenuName.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.imageView);
                final Category clickItem = model;
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this,""+clickItem.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recycler_menu.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id==R.id.list){
        layoutman();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
        if (id==R.id.grid){
            layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_menu) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_cart) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_orders) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_log_out) {

        } else if (id == R.id.share) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change layout manager on click event , for example for Listview Data your layout manager should be

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
```

Below code for Grid View Layout Manager

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

For Simple Listview

```
  RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

then you have to change list view respectively, i hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right but have need to set layout manager on your recyclerview again otherwise it will not work and after that just call notifydatasetchanged() only after that it should work.